# How to set two fonts for a single EditText in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-typeface

This is `ChooseLanguage` class:

```
  languagelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you select "+lag[position]+" language", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     switch (position){
                         case 0:
                             mytranslate.TamilLanguage();
                             list_dialog.hide();
                             break;
                         case 1:
                             mytranslate.EnglishLanguage();
                             list_dialog.hide();
                             break;
                     }
                    }
                });
                list_dialog.show();
            }
```

This is `Translate` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample);

    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input1);
}
public void TamilLanguage(){
    final Typeface tamil_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplication().getAssets(), "Tamil.ttf");
    e1.setTypeface(tamil_font);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you select Tamil Language", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
public void EnglishLanguage(){
    final Typeface english_font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplication().getAssets(), "English.ttf");
    e1.setTypeface(english_font);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you select English Language",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I am choosing Font on `ChooseLanguage` class ,but in `MyTranslate` class it not working, this is my code, please refer it.

If I click a button, it will show a list 1.English 2.Tamil. If I choose a language, it will change edittext font.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you really have a font called `Tamil.ttf` and a font called `English,ttf` in your assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh your current activity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```